# Component tree / Attributes missing on preview

Tags: android-studio

Unlike shown in [Introduction to the Layout Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html#intro), my preview window is missing Component Tree and Attributes view:

[image: Android studio]

Where can I enable those?

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking for preview, but **design view**! Enable it by clicking "Design" button on bottom left of main window.

[image: Android studio]

*(I asked and answered this question because I spent half an hour trying to fix what wasn't broken! I even reinstalled Android Studio, only to find out later that I was in the wrong view -- and I don't want others to make the same stupid mistake.)*